# Magento 2.4.4 Coupon Usage Count Not Reflect in Admin Cart Price Rule

Tags: magento2, coupon, magento2.4.4

Coupon for single use is used multiple times,
ssue
Merchants set up a coupon for single use and customers are able to use it multiple times.

Steps to reproduce:

Create a coupon and configure the coupon to single use.
Proceed to checkout.
Use the coupon that you just created.
Proceed to checkout again and use the same coupon.
Expected result:

The coupon can only be used once. A message displays: The coupon code “COUPON_NAME” is not valid.

Actual result:

The coupon can be used more than once.

Reason behind this is , it is not updating the value at admin side Marketing->cart price rule->manage coupon code tab : https://prnt.sc/QGo1Iuphb1Rs

Please help me about this .

Comment: Your cron running?

Comment: yes cron is working fine .